# how to connect nao robot to android application using sockets

Tags: android, sockets, connection, nao-robot, choregraphe

I want to connect android application to choreographe whitch for example if user click 1 in android studio , the nao robot dance 
how can I apply this ?
I tried with socket but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect an Android application to Choregraphe, nor react on a click in Android Studio. However you can connect an Android application to a robot, and from there run a Choregraphe behavior installed on the robot.

To do so, the best way should be to use [libqi-java](https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-java) which you can recompile for your target Android platform. See the [Android example](https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-java/tree/master/examples/android).

It is not straightforward, but this would grant you a direct access to the API of NAOqi.
The alternative is to use another middleware and bridge it with NAOqi, but this is not recommended, because you may end up opening security holes.

Then, when you have access to NAOqi, use [`ALBehaviorManager.runBehavior("your_app/your_dance")`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager-api.html#ALBehaviorManagerProxy::runBehavior__ssCR).